# Binary Search Tree - PrintInOrder();

Tags: c++

Minha BST (templated class) tem a função `PrintInOrder()`, que não recebe parâmetros:

```
void BST<Type>::printInOrder() const{}
```

Andei procurando na internet, e achei algumas `InOrder()`, porém elas recebem um `Node*` para a raiz como parâmetro, o que faz sentido.

Como eu poderia fazer uma recursão na função que citei sem passar parâmetros?
Há um jeito de eu criar um membro privado na classe como ajuda para isso?

Minha BST classe:

```
struct Node
{
    Type m_data;
    Node *m_left, *m_right;

    Node(const Type& _data) : m_data(_data), m_left(nullptr), m_right(nullptr) {}
};

Node* m_root;
int m_size;

public:
    BST();
    ~BST();
    BST& operator=(const BST& that);
    BST(const BST& that);;
    void insert(const Type& v);
    bool findAndRemove(const Type& v);
    bool find(const Type& v) const;
    void clear();
    void printInOrder() const;
};
```

Comment: O que você pode fazer é criar um método privado que precisa de parâmetro (e implementá-lo da maneira recursiva) e no seu método publico você chama esse privado passando o `m_root`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que falei no meu comentário, seria isso:

```
struct Node
{
    Type m_data;
    Node *m_left, *m_right;

    Node(const Type& _data) : m_data(_data), m_left(nullptr), m_right(nullptr) {}
};

Node* m_root;
int m_size;
void printInOrderRecursive(Node* root);

public:
    BST();
    ~BST();
    BST& operator=(const BST& that);
    BST(const BST& that);;
    void insert(const Type& v);
    bool findAndRemove(const Type& v);
    bool find(const Type& v) const;
    void clear();
    void printInOrder();
};
```

Sendo que a implementação de `void printInOrder();` seria:

```
void printInOrder() {
    printInOrderRecursive(m_root);
}
```

---

Não coloquei a implementação de `void printInOrderRecursive(Node* root);`, pois você disse na pergunta já ter encontrado.